# How to fed Twitterdata via flume to hdfs over proxy?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, proxy, flume-ng

I have installed flume and is trying to feed Twitter data into hdfs folder.

my flume.conf file looks like as:

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, china, india.
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

and I am Encountered with the following error:

```
2014-11-03 02:00:49,834 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG -  twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] User-Agent: twitter4j http://twitter4j.org/ /2.2.6
2014-11-03 02:00:49,834 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] Connection: close
2014-11-03 02:00:49,835 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] X-Twitter-Client-Version: 2.2.6
2014-11-03 02:00:49,835 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] X-Twitter-Client-URL: http://twitter4j.org/en/twitter4j-2.2.6.xml
2014-11-03 02:00:49,836 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] Accept-Encoding: gzip
2014-11-03 02:00:49,836 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] X-Twitter-Client: Twitter4J
2014-11-03 02:00:49,837 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:75)] Post Params: count=0&track=hadoop%2Cbig%20data%2Canalytics%2Cbigdata%2Ccloudera%2Cdata%20science&include_entities=true
2014-11-03 02:00:49,843 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Connection refused
2014-11-03 02:00:49,843 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Waiting for 2000 milliseconds
2014-11-03 02:00:49,843 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Waiting for 2000 milliseconds]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] Twitter Stream consumer-1[Waiting for 2000 milliseconds]
2014-11-03 02:00:51,843 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Waiting for 2000 milliseconds]) [DEBUG - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.debug(SLF4JLogger.java:67)] Connection refused
2014-11-03 02:00:51,844 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Waiting for 2000 milliseconds]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Establishing connection.
```

My college Network is equipped with proxy server. I think the problem is due to proxy sever.

How can I use a proxy with flume?

Comment: guys plz share if u got any solution

Answer (score 3):

Build the jar from https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

Unzip, then execute inside (as mentionned) :

go to /cdh-twitter-example-master/flume-sources/src/main/java/com/cloudera/flume/source/TwitterSource.java

and add this lines

```
cb.setHttpProxyHost("your proxy");
cb.setHttpProxyPort(8080);//port
cb.setHttpProxyUser("");
cb.setHttpProxyPassword("");
```

$ cd flume-sources

$ mvn package

den put the jar from target to flume lib folder.enjoy

Comment: That's exactly the solution.