# applying twitter proxy plug in fix not working

Tags: java

I am following this link to fix the issue I have in using FLUME behind the twitter :
[[How to fed Twitterdata via flume to hdfs over proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704206/how-to-fed-twitterdata-via-flume-to-hdfs-over-proxy][1])

but its giving me following error:

> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flume-sources: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cloudera:flume-sources:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.99.x86_64/jre/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Comment: after installing JDK maven compiled successfully but my issue still remains.  now its giving different error though

Comment: Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.Status.getRetweetCount()J
        at org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.extractRecord(TwitterSource.java:248)